# Regex - extract the numbers only - unless "..." is encountered

Tags: regex, pcre

Consider a variable length string starting with a variable number of digits, then a non-digit, then anything.

```
Eg. 283432478($#*a433sd
```

(ignore SO's coloring)

Here I would like to extract the digit part `283432478`. No big deal.

However sometimes this string is very large and a portion in the middle has been manually and haphazardly replaced by `...`

```
Eg. 23445678404325jkla#$s23k$#$     =>     2344567840...3k$#$
```

By haphazardly I mean it could happen anywhere within the string, nor does it result in a fixed length string.

I would like the same regular expression to fail matching if it sees a `...`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for editing the title Michael - I was stumped how to word it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
^([0-9]+)(?!.*\.\.\.)
```

[**See it**](http://www.rubular.com/r/iz338WGUko)

```
^            - Start anchor
([0-9]+)     - Capture one more digits
(?!.*\.\.\.) - Negative lookahead to ensure a ... is not present. Since . is a 
               regex meta-char, you need to escape it to mean a literal period.
```

Comment: I can see it definitely works but I don't understand what is stopping [0-9]+ matching 2344567 in the 2344567840...3k$#$ string above, and (?!.*\.\.\.) matching 840? I would have thought it would go for a match over the greediness of the +

Comment: @jontyc Go through this: goo.gl/yW9x7s